# jQuery dialog will not show the close icon

Tags: jquery, html, css

I embeded a jQuery dialog (https://jqueryui.com/dialog/)

My problem is that the icon "x" will not shown:

[image]

But I don't know why.
I include the complete code from the example and embedded this into my website. any Ideas, what this can be?

**Code**

```
<html lang="de">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery-ui.min.css">
</head>

<body>
    <a href="javascript:openDialog()">Open Dialog</a>
    <div id="dialog-confirm" title="Title" style="display: none;">
        <p>Text</p>
    </div>




<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    function openDialog() {
        alert
        $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
            "Close": function() {
              $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
          }
        });
    };
</script>




</body></html>
```

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: Has same issue in other browsers?

Comment: Your missing the theme images `url("images/ui-icons_777777_256x240.png")` etc.

Comment: At a guess, you aren't using the CDN for the CSS? If you copied the CSS to your local machine, and didn't copy the images, then the image paths may no longer point properly. Purely a wild stab in the dark, as we haven't been given anything to work from.

Comment: @Lawrence Cherone: this images is available

Comment: Could it be that your button is the same colour as the image, so you simply can't see it?

Comment: Check the browser console and network tab for any errors.

Comment: I can reproduce this: https://imgur.com/a/Pa59j, i'm not convinced. Or you put a `display:none` on `.ui-button .ui-icon`

Comment: The image might be "available" - but it might be that your linking it / including it incorrectly (as per other comments).

Comment: I updated my first post with my code.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.
The images were in the folder "images" => wrong.
Correct => "css/images"

Comment: It helped me.Great

Answer (score 0):

look that has implemented the jquery, jquery ui well

This is the one in charge of showing the x

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
```

this is jquery and jquery ui

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Look for styles and routes